# Adjective to describe a "friend from a long time ago"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I you I: "My older friends didn't come either." It could mean a) my friends from a long time ago b) my friends that are older than me.

Is there an adjective that removes this ambiguity?

Comment: ***old*** not *older*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ***[longtime](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/longtime) friend*** is the expression you are looking for:

> having been so for a long time :  long-standing.
>
> - a longtime friend a longtime friendship*.

(W-B)

Comment: I would use *longtime* for friendships that started a long time a go and that have endured to the present.  But friendships made years ago that have drifted apart over time (due to having moved away for example) are just ***old*** friends.  *I invited some old friends that I haven’t seen in years*)